# Php replace not functioning?

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, str-replace

im return this url into  array

```
$imagelink = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ."/test/wp-content/plugins/test/captcha/" .$captchaURL.".jpeg";
```

when i    `return $imagelink;` in one of my array it shows this :

"Image URL":"localhost/test/wp-content/plugins/test/captcha/LTgLUodmPu.jpeg"

i try to replace the /

```
$imagelink = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ."/test/wp-content/plugins/test/captcha/" .$captchaURL.".jpeg";
$replace = str_replace('\/','/',$imagelink);
return $replace;
```

the result is still the same ? it doesn't seems to replace. why?
its the same as i also use preg_replace() function.

please help if you have the ans.

Comment: With what you want to replace ?

Comment: Replace `/` with `/`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes **"** while escaping the string

> $replace = str_replace("\/","\\",$imagelink);

Comment: I have updated the code. $replace = str_replace("\/","\\",$imagelink);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to replace forward slashes with forward slashes.
Try either of these:

```
$imagelink = str_replace('\\', '/', $imagelink); // Replace backslash with forward
$imagelink = str_replace('/', '\\', $imagelink); // Replace forwardslash with backslash
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<?php 
$imagelink = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ."/test/wp-content/plugins/test/captcha/" .$captchaURL.".jpeg";
$replace = str_replace('/','\\',$imagelink);
return $replace;
```